# Comparing string date with today's date

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, compare

So I have a string which is "2014-06-30 15:27" and if it is today's date it should only return "15:27" else "30/06/2014". I've already tried simpleDateFormat.parse but it didn't work very well.

```
holder.data.setText(mensagem.getDate());
```

Comment: work around with this format http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Check out this one http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    final String stringDate = "2014-07-17 23:59";

    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    Date date = inputFormat.parse(stringDate);

    Calendar calendarDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarDate.setTime(date);

    Calendar midnight = Calendar.getInstance();
    midnight.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    midnight.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    midnight.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    midnight.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    if (calendarDate.compareTo(midnight) >= 0)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        System.out.println(timeFormat.format(date));
    }
    else
    {
        SimpleDateFormat dateTimeForm = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
        System.out.println(dateTimeForm.format(date));
    }
```

Comment: You forgot that 1) The incoming date might also be midnight (so, equal - unfortunately you can't use the `.equals(...)` method due to it considering things like timezone, you'd need `compareTo(...)` , which would also allow you to do the comparison in one go), 2) that timestamps have fractional seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've made a couple of edits to the code.  Calendar.HOUR was a typo, should have been Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY.  Now using compareTo on Calendar for the date comparison.  I also cleared the milliseconds on the midnight value.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

## `LocalDateTime`

First parse the string as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html). Replace the SPACE in the middle with `T` to comply with standard ISO 8601 format. The java.time classes support ISO 8601 formats by default.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse ( "2014-06-30 15:27".replace ( " " , "T" ) );
```

> ldt.toString(): 2014-06-30T15:27

Such a value has no real meaning. The input string lacked any clue about offset-from-UTC or time zone. So we do not know if this is 3 PM in Auckland NZ or 3 PM in Québec Canada, two very different moments. You should to assign the offset or time zone indicated by your business situation. Search Stack Overflow for how to do this, focussing on classes `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime`. I'll skip over this crucial issue for now.

## `LocalDate`

Extract a date-only value. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = ldt.toLocalDate();
```

## Today

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

## Comparison

You can compare [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) objects by calling methods such as `compareTo`, `equals`, `isEqual`, `isBefore`, `isAfter`.

```
if( today.isEqual( ld ) ) {
    return ldt.toLocalTime();
} else {
    return ld;
}
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

As the `java.time` library is the recommended way to use date and time. So, to compare current date with a string date you need to first convert date in string format to `java.time.LocalDate` :

```
LocalDate paresedStringDate = LocalDate.parse("2022-11-10");
```

After that you can get the current date using below code:

```
LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
```

And then you can compare both the current date and parsed string date to check if both are same using below code:

```
if (paresedStringDate.compareTo(currentDate) == 0) {
   //do what you want to do here
}
```

Comment: Still clearer to read: `paresedStringDate.isEqual(currentDate)`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the Date class...

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date exitdate = df.parse("2019-01-17");
Date currdate = new Date();
long diff = currdate.getTime() - exitdate.getTime();
long days = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

if(days==0)
{
    System.out.println("IS TRUE"+currdate.toString());
    return true;
}
```