# How to compare a date string to current date?

Tags: java, android, datetime, java.util.date, date-comparison

I have a date picker through which I am setting up a date in string i.e. mDate.
Now to set up time I want to check if current date and the mDate is same if they are same I want to set minTime to TimePicker dialog and if they are not same min time should not be set to time.

If mDate is empty still time should show all time.

```
   mEditTxt_Time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Date date = null;
                try {

                    if(!mDate.equals("")) {
                        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
                        date = format.parse(mDate);
                    }

                    Calendar compareDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                    compareDate.getTime();

                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

                TimePickerDialog tpd = TimePickerDialog.newInstance(
                        PostShippingFragment.this,
                        now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                        now.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                        true
                );

                    if(date!=null) {
                        if (date.compareTo(compareDate.getTime())) {
                            tpd.setMinTime(now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), now.get(Calendar.MINUTE), now.get(Calendar.SECOND));
                        }
                    }
                    else {

                        tpd.setVersion(TimePickerDialog.Version.VERSION_2);

                        tpd.setAccentColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorAccent));

                        tpd.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                                Log.d("TimePicker", "Dialog was cancelled");
                            }
                        });


                        tpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Timepickerdialog");
                    }
            }
                catch (ParseException e)
                {
                    Log.e("exception",e.toString());

                }
            }
        });
```

I tried this but I am not able to do the comparison.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: what about equals method of the date class`?

Comment: When posting code, it's always a good idea to keep it minimal - in your question, at least 50% of the code is completely unrelated to your question.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592501/how-to-compare-dates-in-java

Comment: You can make use of the simple solution offered here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53963322/3056868

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `compareTo()` method of Date.

It will return an **integer** value,

- return a value **0** if the argument Date (compareDate) is **equal** to this Date;
- return a value **less than 0** if this Date is **before** the Date argument (compareDate);
- return a value **greater than 0** if this Date is **after** the Date
  argument (compareDate).

So, you need to modify your `if condition` as below, if you want to check both date are same or not.

```
if (date.compareTo(compareDate.getTime()) == 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the following method to compare the dates

**Method 1**

- date1.after(date2)
- date1.before(date2)
- date1.equals(date2)

**Method 2**

```
if(date1.compareTo(date2)>0){
  Log.d("Date", "Date1 is after Date2");
}else if(date1.compareTo(date2)<0){
    Log.d("Date", "Date1 is before Date2");
}else{
      Log.d("Date", "Date1 is equal to Date2");
}
```

**Method 3**

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTime(date1);
cal2.setTime(date2);
```

- cal1.after(cal2)
- cal1.before(cal2)
- cal1.equals(cal2)

Comment: Nice. What are the advantages of each method? Can you help us pick?